# SQL query for for finding range between two numbers, to stop duplicates to enter

Tags: sql

I have a data in a table with two columns `from` and `to`, for example: `5-9`.

If I insert a new row `1-6`, it should NOT be accepted, as `6` lies in between `5` and `9`.

`1-3` - should accept (no overlap), `10-13` - should also accept.

I need a single query for this

Comment: What SQL engine are you using?

Comment: What is your database system?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if not exist (select * from table where @from between [from] and [to])
begin 
  if not exist (select * from table where @to between [from] and [to])
    begin 
    if not exist(select * from table where [from] between @from and @to)
       begin 
          insert into table 
                select @from, @to
       end
    end
end
```

Comment: First [exist] check if your input range [from] already exist in existing range; Second [exist] check if your input range [to] already exist in existing data; third one is in case your input range actually cover the existing range, for example input is 1-100

Comment: What if records already are 5-6,4-5,2-7 and iam adding 1-8.As 1 is not in between existing records and 8 as well..

Comment: Do you want to add 1-8 or not to add 1-8, with 5-6 already exist? the sample query I give will not add 1-8, it is filtered out by third [not exist]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on SQL vendor, implementation will differ, but idea is the same: you need to create a `TRIGGER` on `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

This is a solution for PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id SERIAL, 
    m1 INTEGER, 
    m2 INTEGER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytable_fn()
RETURNS trigger AS
$body$
DECLARE cnt INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) INTO cnt
    FROM mytable
    WHERE numrange(NEW.m1, NEW.m2)
       && numrange(    m1,     m2);
    IF cnt > 0 THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Constraint violation';
               ELSE RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER mytable_tr
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON mytable FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE mytable_fn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @from INT
DECLARE @to INT

SET @from = 14
SET @to = 16

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE @from BETWEEN [from] AND [to]
                                OR @to BETWEEN [from] AND [to]
                                OR @from <= [from] AND @to >= [to])
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Table1([from], [to]) VALUES(@from, @to)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  --Already Exists
END
```